# Generate all numbers of the binary system (B=2, t=3, L=-2, U=3)

Tags: matlab, binary, floating-point, radix

Suppose we have the following binary system

```
(B=2, t=3, L=-2, U=3)
```

where `B` is the base of the system, since it's a binary system, `B` is of course 2. `t` is the precision of the number, usually refers to how many digits there are in the normalized floating-point number (except of course the exponents). `L` is the lower bound for the exponent and, similarly, `U` is the upper bound for the exponent.

I've the following Matlab script which generates all numbers for this binary system:

```
x = [];

for i = 1:0.25:1.75,
    for j =  2:3,
        x = [x i*2^j];
    end 
end

x = [x, -x 0]; % Add all negative numbers and 0
x = sort(x);
```

I understand more or less all the statements in this code, except why `i` goes from 1 to 1.75 in steps of 0.25, or 1/4.

I understood why it starts from 1 and ends at 1.75, because basically the smallest positive number is 1.00<sub>2</sub> = 1<sub>10</sub> and the highest is 1.11<sub>2</sub> = 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 = 1.75<sub>10</sub>, but why in steps of 0.25 or 1/4?

Comment: Because 0.25_b10 = 0.01_b2 which is your least significant digit. (I haven't really carefully read your detailed description before.. or I didn't get it.)

Comment: @MatthiasW. Yes, I understood it in the meanwhile... So, usually, to generate all numbers in a certain system, we use the same pattern, but instead of using 0.25, we use the smallest fraction that we possible can represent in that system. So, if t=4, the step in the first loop would be 0.001, etc.